# PowerShell - advice to get script slimmer

Tags: powershell

I have the following PS script that repeats in the two blocks the same amount of registry keys. So I have two questions:

1. How can I avoid to repeat that long list of reg keys? I've tried adding them to a variable that is assigned @"  "@, but when I use the variable instead of the reg keys it does not work
2. The $faultReport does not get the addition when into the Catch block, how to fix that?

   ```
   $faultReport = @()

   if (Test-Connection $2FQDN -Quiet -count 2) {
       Try { 
           Invoke-Command -ComputerName $1FQDN -ScriptBlock {        
               Loads of registry keys
           }
    }
    Catch {
        $faultReport += $1FQDN}
    } 
   elseif (Test-Connection $2FQDN -Quiet -count 2) {
        Try {      
            Invoke-Command -ComputerName $2FQDN -ScriptBlock {
                Loads of registry keys
            }
        }        
        Catch {
            $faultReport += $2FQDN
        }
   }
   ```

Comment: How are the registry keys supplied? A csv list? Basically, do a `Foreach ($RegKey in $RegKeys) { ... }` or create your own function: `Handle RegKeys ($RegKeys, $AdditionalParams) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to assign a scriptblock to a variable

```
$scriptBlock = { ... }
```

Also you have an error in your code: You check the connection for `$2FQDN` (instead of `$1FQDN`) in your first `if`.

Additionally, you could simplify your code further: both bodies of the if-else are identical.

My suggestion:

```bsh
$scriptBlock = {
    # Loads of registry keys...
}
$faultReport = @()
$computerName = $null
if (Test-Connection $1FQDN -Quiet -count 2) {
    $computerName = $1FQDN
}
elseif (Test-Connection $2FQDN -Quiet -count 2) {
    $computerName = $2FQDN
}
if ($computerName) {
    try {      
         Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
    }
    Catch {
        $faultReport += $computerName
    }
}
```

Note: Always use proper indentation. I can never stress that enough. It makes reading and troubleshooting your own code so much easier.

Comment: many thanks! That is it.. definitely slim and light. Also the $faultReport is filled correctly at each loop. About the error in my original script it was just due to me masking the real names here in public. If you have two more minutes.. would you mind telling me why in my case the  $faultReport was not getting filled? No worries if you have no time... thanks anyway

Comment: @Lothar I am really not sure why. I thought it was because of your error in the code ($1FQDN/$2FQDN). And since I cannot run your code on my machine I don't really have a way to test.